# Reducing garbage-collection time while using large data structures in a functional language

Tags: garbage-collection, scheme, lisp, racket

How can you reduce garbage-collection time while using large data structures in a functional language?

(I'm using Racket but the question would apply to any functionally oriented language with a garbage collector.)

The core idiom of functional programming is that you design functions to work on a copy of the data, and return the processed data as a result, instead of mutating data structures from afar. You don't worry about the extra copying because a garbage collector comes by and recovers memory that's no longer in use.

That's great as far as it goes. But as I've started writing programs that handle larger data structures, I find that more of the total run time is being occupied by garbage collection (as in 25-35% rather than the 10-15% that I found typical with small structures).

That's not surprising, because more data is being copied for each function call, and thus there's more garbage to collect.

But it also makes speed improvements more difficult, since more of the run time is taken up by the garbage collector, which is essentially outside your control.

The obvious solution would be to avoid copying the data at all. But this puts you back into mutating data from afar, which contradicts the functional idiom. (Though I know this can be done to some degree in Racket by using boxed values, or even with parameters.)

Beyond that, three options occur to me:

1. Design your data structures so that they encode information more compactly.
2. Rather than passing whole data structures to functions, pull out the subset of data you need to process (though of course that assumes that cost of separating & rejoining the data subset saves enough garbage-collection time to be worth it).
3. Where possible, combine multiple functions (which would ordinarily pass the large data structure from one to the next, copying it each time) into a single, tail-recursive function (which will not).

Are these effective approaches? Are there others I'm overlooking?

Comment: Perhaps using [Transducers](http://youtu.be/6mTbuzafcII) might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn’t a perfect answer, but it’s more on-topic than other resources I found. This paper, “Functional Data Structures in Typed Racket,” discusses alternative functional data structures that perform better than standard lists in certain contexts, and gives specific timing results that includes garbage-collection time (HT Greg Hendershott):

http://www.ccs.neu.edu/racket/pubs/sfp10-kth.pdf

And here is the code for the implementations:

https://github.com/takikawa/tr-pfds

Answer (score 4):

There are functional data structures that are designed to reduce the cost of copying - for example, if a function mutates a branch of a tree, then the new tree would share the nodes from the unaffected branches and only the mutated branch would need to be copied.

Chris Okasaki's [Purely Functional Data Structures](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) is the best paper on this that I am aware of, but there is probably more recent research that I am unaware of (for example, the [ctrie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctrie), that I only know of through Wikipedia).

Comment: For example: [Functional Data Structures for Typed Racket](https://github.com/takikawa/tr-pfds).

Answer (score 0):

Producing a lot of unnecessary garbage is, of course, bad. If the profiler is showing that you are allocating a lot of memory, and that the GC is successfully recovering a lot of memory, you should think about producing less garbage. That's one place where your (1) comes in:

> Design your data structures so that they encode information more compactly.

That's really important in general. If GC time is hurting performance, try using more compact data structures. If GC time is *not* hurting performance, try using more compact data structures. Compact data structures improve both GC performance and cache utilization. If you can cram more information into the CPU cache in fewer bytes, you can often get dramatic speed improvements.

Your (2) and (3), on the other hand, look pretty fishy, and suggest to me that you may not have a clear sense of how values are actually represented in memory. Passing a structure to a function does *not* generally copy it in typical functional language implementations. That said, "pull out the subset of data you need to process" can make sense, because if the rest might not be needed, you can turn it into garbage more quickly, which is good.

The last thing is that 25-35% GC time may sound kind of bad, but it's not nearly as bad as it can be. The worst I've seen is when the "weak generational hypothesis" is violated. That is, when you allocate a bunch of memory that does *not* become garbage quickly. This is bad because the garbage collector keeps trying to collect garbage, tracing more and more non-garbage, without actually accomplishing much. I've personally seen GC times of up to around 75% in these cases, but I wouldn't be surprised if it could be worse than that.